# How to show if a function f is open/not open

Tags: general-topology, functions

could you help me out?

Let the real function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x)=x^2$. Show that $f$ is not open.

How do I go about doing this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: A good place to start would be to very carefully write down the definition of an "open function" and attempting to see if the function $f : \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R} : x \mapsto x^2$ satisfies this definition.  Edit the definition and your attempts into the question, let us know where you get stuck, and perhaps someone will be able to help.

Answer (score 2):

To show $f$ is not open, you need to show that there is some open set $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(U)$, the image of $U$ under $f$, is not open in the codomain ($\mathbb{R}$).

Consider, for example, the open interval $(-2,2)$.  What is $f( (-2,2))$?  Is it open?

Answer (score 0):

Try to see what $f$ does to some open intervals. What $x$ value is particularly interesting for this function? See what happens with an open interval containing that value!

Answer (score 0):

To show that a map is not open you just need to find an open set in the domain whose image is not open in the codomain.

Hint: $f(\mathbb{R})=[0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

You could use that a continuous open function is strictly monotonic. The proof is not difficult, see here: [To prove $f$ to be a monotone function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/419978/to-prove-f-to-be-a-monotone-function).
 Is $f$ stricly monotonic ?